# boolean text search in python

Tags: python, full-text-search, boolean

i'm looking for an existing module(s) which enabled me to write basic boolean queries for matching and searching texts, WITHOUT writing my own parser etc.

for example,

```
president AND (ronald OR (george NOT bush))
```

would match TRUE against
"the president ronald ragen"
"the president ronald ragen and bush"
"max bush was not a president"

but False on
"george bush was a president"
"i don't know how to spell ronald ragen"

(So far i found Booleano, which seems a bit overkill, but could do the task. However their group is inactive, and i couldn't figure out from the documentation what to do.)

thanks

Edit:
the exact style or grammer is not critical. my aim is to provide non-tech users with the ability to search certain texts a bit beyond keyword search.

Comment: +1 for “ragan” … and for the question. ;)

Comment: By the way, for the expression that you have, "max bush was not a president" should be false I would think.

Comment: what's up with your NOT operator, bit suss

Comment: @Matt Joiner: i didn't understand your question. Maybe i should be "(george AND NOT bush)" ? donno..

Comment: yeah that's kind of what I was thinking, i donno either

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I am the creator of the package presented below.

For the people who might come to this page: I built a package to do just that (still in beta).

```
pip install eldar
```

Your query would be translated in the following code:

```py
from eldar import Query

eldar = Query('"president" AND ("ronald" OR ("george" AND NOT "bush"))')

print(eldar("President Bush"))
# >>> False
print(eldar("President George"))
# >>> True
```

You can use it on some pandas dataframe as well, check the git page for more info:
https://github.com/kerighan/eldar

Comment: While this answer ***may look like spam*** to some casual observers/reviewers, I think it does actually meet the requirements for self-promotion (which is clearly stated). It also directly addresses the question asked.

Comment: should I edit my answer and remove the github link ? I don't care about promotion, I just wanted to be transparent.

Comment: You don't need to remove or change anything! Your post came up in review as "a new user's answer to an old question" and I put that comment in to help other reviewers.

Comment: i accepted this answer because it seems right. However - I haven't tested it.

Comment: @BerryTsakala perhaps if you tested you would have noticed that literally copy paste of this answer OR the first "basic usage" example on github link don't work properly.

Comment: @okkko thanks for the bug report. There was a mistake in the latest version. No need to be condescending, I'm only trying to help the community. It's fixed on the 0.0.6. Next time post a little something on github.

Comment: @Kerighan Thanks for the effort and update but the github basic example is still not working properly - eldar(documents[2]) returns True.

Comment: @okko thanks for the comment. Ok so it works as expected as "movies" is not "movie" : by default match_word=True, so words should match exactly. It's a readme mistake, I'll update it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

It would be pretty lucky to find a pre-existing library that happens to be ready to parse the example expression that you provided. I recommend making your expression format a bit more machine readable, while retaining all of its clarity. A Lisp S-expression (which uses prefix notation) is compact and clear:

(and "president" (or "ronald" "george" "sally"))

Writing a parser for this format is easier than for your format. Or you could just switch to Lisp and it will parse it natively. :)

Side note: I assume you didn't mean to make your "NOT" operator binary, right?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [simpleBool.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py) code on [this page](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples?f=print) that uses the pyparsing module. Otherwise, here's some simple code I wrote.

This isn't a module, but it might get you in the right direction.

```
def found(s,searchstr):
    return s.find(searchstr)>-1

def booltest1(s):
    tmp = found(s,'george') and not found(s,'bush')
    return found(s,'president') and (found(s,'ronald') or tmp)

print booltest1('the president ronald reagan')
print booltest1('george bush was a president')
```

and you can test other ones. I used tmp because the line was getting so long

Comment: thanks, but your example is not a general purpose routine. simpleBool, seems interesting, but requires lots of work to adapt to the text-domain.

Answer (score 1):

I use [sphinx for full text search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) from python in my website. It has a simple syntax that supports [boolean matchings](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#boolean-syntax), but with operators, not words. For example, your query would be `president (regan|(bush -george))`.

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) has the [same feature](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators).